# No tests found in TestClass Haven't you forgot @Test annotation?

Tags: java, mockito, junit4

I am getting an error like this when running my test:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 

No tests found in TestCase
Haven't you forgot @Test annotation?
```

I certainly do have a method annotated with `@Test`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see how this question is off-topic. Please clarify why you think that so I can improve it.

Comment: I am using currently JUnit 5 and Mockito v1.10.19. Facing the same proble, though writing the test methods with public access specifier. Any advice?

Comment: @ParameshKorrakuti Never used Junit 5. If there is no question about Junit5, just create a new question.

Comment: Probably next time when you ask a question, you should share your code with us. And  I had the same problem, of course.

Comment: @32cupo Here you go: `@Test void asdf() {}`.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The method needs to be explicitly declared as `public`:

```
@Test
public void asdf() {
    asdf...
}
```

Answer (score 68):

I got this exception even though I had a public method annotaded with `@Test`. Turned out was importing `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`, I changed to `org.junit.Test` and it worked fine.

Comment: This means you have both the Junit 4.x and Junit 5.x libraries on your classpath but you likely don't have all the required dependencies for 5.x, or whatever runner you are using isn't updated to be able to run 5.x. The junit 5.x has the capability to run 4.x tests

Comment: Saved a lot of time!

Answer (score 9):

Import junit package in stead of testng package.

Comment: Bingo! @Test annotation was from TestNG testing library indeed. Changing to JUnit in imports helped.

Answer (score 7):

If you've upgraded to Junit 5, according to this [How to use Mockito with JUnit5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40961057/how-to-use-mockito-with-junit5):

"No Rules, No Runners
JUnit 4 rules and runners don't work in JUnit 5, so the MockitoRule and the Mockito runner can not be used."

Use @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) instead. Verified this on Junit 5.6.2 and Spring boot 2.3.1:

`@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) @MockitoSettings(strictness = Strictness.LENIENT) public class ClassTest {}`

Don't also forget to explicitly declare the test method as public as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the public access modifier from the test class
and go with the

```html
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
```

Comment: This is incorrect answer. You need `import org.junit.Test` and NOT `import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`

Answer (score 1):

you need to check the import of the test in the class for example from :`import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;`
into: `import org.junit.Test;`

Answer (score 0):

Class has be public
test method has be public