# How to use Mockito with JUnit 5?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, junit5

How can I use injection with Mockito and JUnit 5?

In JUnit 4, I can just use the `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` annotation.
In JUnit 5, there is no `@RunWith` Annotation.

Answer (score 329, accepted):

There are different ways to use Mockito - I'll go through them one by one.

### Manually

Creating mocks manually with [`Mockito::mock`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.28/org/mockito/Mockito.html#mock(java.lang.Class)) works regardless of the JUnit version (or test framework for that matter).

### Annotation Based

Using the [@Mock](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.28/org/mockito/Mock.html)-annotation and the corresponding call to [`MockitoAnnotations::initMocks`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.28/org/mockito/MockitoAnnotations.html)
 to [create mocks](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.28/org/mockito/Mockito.html#9) works regardless of the JUnit version (or test framework for that matter but Java 9 could interfere here, depending on whether the test code ends up in a module or not).

### Mockito Extension

JUnit 5 has [a powerful extension model](https://blog.codefx.org/design/architecture/junit-5-extension-model/) and Mockito recently published one under the group / artifact ID [*org.mockito* : *mockito-junit-jupiter*](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.mockito%22%20AND%20a%3A%22mockito-junit-jupiter%22).

You can apply the extension by adding `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` to the test class and annotating mocked fields with `@Mock`. From `MockitoExtension`'s JavaDoc:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ExampleTest {

    @Mock
    private List list;

    @Test
    public void shouldDoSomething() {
        list.add(100);
    }

}
```

[The MockitoExtension documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-junit-jupiter/3.3.3/org/mockito/junit/jupiter/MockitoExtension.html) describes other ways to instantiate mocks, for example with constructor injection (if you rpefer final fields in test classes).

### No Rules, No Runners

JUnit 4 rules and runners don't work in JUnit 5, so the [`MockitoRule`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.28/org/mockito/junit/MockitoRule.html) and the [Mockito runner](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.28/org/mockito/junit/MockitoJUnitRunner.html) can not be used.

Comment: There is now an official Mockito Junit5 Extension that is the equivalent to the MockitoJUnitRunner -> mockito-junit-jupiter

Comment: When the official extension for Mockito was released, wrote a blog post with more details how to configure and use it: https://solidsoft.wordpress.com/2018/03/27/convenient-mocking-in-mockito-with-junit-5-the-official-way/

Comment: Does the method annotated with `@Test` needs to be public or "package private" is good enough?

Comment: When running tests with Jupiter (often referred to as "JUnit 5"), test methods only need to be package-visible.

Comment: Coming back to this - is there a preferred way? Any recommendations? Or is it opinion based?

Comment: To my knowledge, no approach has became the accepted default.

Answer (score 89):

Use Mockito's [`MockitoExtension`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-junit-jupiter/4.5.1/org/mockito/junit/jupiter/MockitoExtension.html). The extension is contained in a new artifact `mockito-junit-jupiter`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

It allows you to write tests as you would have with JUnit 4:

```
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class MyTest {

    @Mock
    private Foo foo;

    @InjectMocks
    private Bar bar; // constructor injection

    ...
}
```

Comment: `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` is equivalent of `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` of the JUnit4

Comment: Can I do multiple calls of the method with different return values on a Mock object's method using MockitoExtension.class in JUnit5

Comment: @RajHassani Yes you can, see [here](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#stubbing_consecutive_calls).

Answer (score 14):

There are different ways to do but the cleaner way and that also respects the JUnit 5 philosophy is creating a  `org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.Extension` for Mockito.

1) [Creating mocks manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806345/runwithmockitojunitrunner-class-vs-mockitoannotations-initmocksthis) makes lose the benefit of additional Mockito checks to ensure you use correctly the framework.

2) Calling `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` in every test classes is boiler plate code that we could avoid.
And making this setup in an abstract class is not a good solution either.
It couples every test classes to a base class.
If then you need a new base test class for good reasons, you finish with a 3- level class hierarchy. Please avoid that.

3) Test Rules is a JUnit 4 specificity.
Don't even think of that.
And the [documentation](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#dependency-metadata-junit-platform) is clear about that :

> However, if you intend to develop a new extension for JUnit 5 please
>   use the new extension model of JUnit Jupiter instead of the rule-based
>   model of JUnit 4.

4) Test Runner is really not the way to extend the JUnit 5 framework.
JUnit 5 simplified the hell of the Runners of JUnit 4 by providing an extension model for writing tests thanks to JUnit 5 Extensions.
Don't even think of that.

So favor the `org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.Extension` way.

---

EDIT : Actually,  Mockito bundles a jupiter extension : [`mockito-junit-jupiter`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-junit-jupiter/2.17.1)

Then, very simple to use :

```
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class FooTest {
     ...    
}
```

Here is an addition to the excellent answer of Jonathan.

By adding as dependency the `mockito-junit-jupiter` artifact, the use of `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` produced the following exception as the test is executed :

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.junit.platform.commons.support.AnnotationSupport.findAnnotation(Ljava/util/Optional;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/Optional;

THe problem is that  `mockito-junit-jupiter` depends on two independent libraries. 
For example for `mockito-junit-jupiter:2.19.0` :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.19.0</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.0</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

The problem was I used `junit-jupiter-api:5.0.1`.

So as `junit-jupiter-api` moves still often in terms of API, make sure you depend on the same version of `junit-jupiter-api` that `mockito-junit-jupiter` depends on.

Comment: why doesn't `mockito-junit-jupiter` pull the proper version of `junit-jupiter-api`?

Comment: @haelix Because the version strategy used for this dependency relies on Mockito library. Look at the version here `mockito-junit-jupiter:2.19.0`. While JUnit Jupiter versions start with `5`. mockito-junit-jupiter should have specified in its artifact identifier the two things (Mockito version and JUnit Jupiter version) to make things clearer. For example `mockito-junit-jupiter-5.1:2.19.0` to convey that the library is designed for JUnit Jupiter 5.1.

Comment: `MockitoExtension` doesn't appear to exist in `mockito-core` version 3.0.0.

Comment: @Thunderforge  This is defined in `mockito-junit-jupiter`

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the new `@ExtendWith` annotation.

Unfortunately there is no extension released yet.
On [github](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/blob/master/junit5-mockito-extension/src/main/java/com/example/mockito/MockitoExtension.java) you can see a beta implementation for the extension. as a example [demo test](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/blob/master/junit5-mockito-extension/src/test/java/com/example/mockito/MockitoExtensionInBaseClassTest.java).

Comment: Link is broken, Page not found

Comment: The extension already exists, see other answers

Answer (score 1):

For **Kotlin** and when annotating a field, make sure to mark it with `lateinit`:

```kotlin
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class MyTest {
    @Mock
    lateinit var list: List

    @Test
    fun `Test should work`() {
        list.add(100)
    }
}
```