# Using MockitoExtension in JUnit 5

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit5

In the [JUnit 5 user guide](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/) we can find a link to [MockitoExtension](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/blob/r5.0.0-M4/junit5-mockito-extension/src/main/java/com/example/mockito/MockitoExtension.java), as an usage example of `TestInstancePostProcessor`, `ParameterResolver` (part of the *Extension API*).

My doubt is about the real usage of Mockito in JUnit 5 (related to this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40961057/how-to-use-mockito-with-junit5)).

- As of now, is that `MockitoExtension` the recommended way to inject mocks within Jupiter tests?
- If so, should I include a copy of that class in my project and then use it? (not the best way I guess)
- Is there any plan to support an official Mockito extension for JUnit 5?

Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm a maintainer of the new and so far unreleased project [JUnit Pioneer](https://github.com/junit-pioneer/junit-pioneer). We actually [plan to polish and release the Mockito extension prototype](https://github.com/junit-pioneer/junit-pioneer/issues/43) to make it easily available until Mockito developed their own.

Comment: @Nicolai Any updates?