# What is mockito-inline and how does it work to mock final methods?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito

Javadocs in Mockito says - "Starting with version 2.7.6, we offer the 'mockito-inline' artifact that enables inline mock making without configuring the MockMaker extension file". What does this mean? How does mockito-inline works ? Why a separate artifact for mockito-inline?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I stumbled upon this too and the answer is [buried quite deep in the docs](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#39), so here it is.

Mockito optionally offers advanced mocking features like mocking final classes. For this to work, they use a different mechanism ("mock maker") that is considered experimental and therefore turned off by default. But:

> **As a convenience**, the Mockito team provides an artifact where this mock maker is preconfigured. Instead of using the *mockito-core* artifact, include the *mockito-inline* artifact in your project.

Comment: Since v5 Mockito uses mokito-inline by default: *Mockito 5 switches the default mockmaker to mockito-inline, and now requires Java 11.*