# Mockito Spy behaves like Mock

Tags: java, mockito

Environment: Java11, AWS Lambda, Dagger, JUnit5 (5.9.1), Mockito(4.8.1) (tried both mockito core & inline)

I have classes A, B and C.
C is injected to B and B is injected to A.
Method A.ma1() calls B.mb1() and B.mb1 calls C.mc1()

I just want to verify if a method "mc1" of C is called or not if I call A.ma1

Here is my structure:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class Test {

  @InjectMocks
  A a;

  @Spy
  B b;

  @Mock
  C c;

  @Test
  public void test() { 
    a.ma1();
    verify(c).mc1(any());
  }
}
```

The problem is when A.ma1() calls B.mb1(),  B.mb1() behaves like a Mock instead of a Spy.
The contents of the method never being executed during debugging, but immediately returning. I also tried to annotate B with @InjectMocks along with @Spy. It also did not work, throwing a different kind of exception.

Does anybody have any idea why does B behave like a Mock instead of a Spy?

Added after comment:
Here is the complete code: (simplified)
AService is A, InternalService is B and PanelDao is C in the above example. B's "selectMappedInternal" never executes line by line but returns immediately like a mock when called.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class Test {

  @InjectMocks
  AService  aService ;

  @Spy
  InternalService  internalService ;

  @Mock
  PanelDao panelDao;

  @Test
  public void test() { 
    ..
  }
}

public class AService {

    @Inject
    InternalService internalService;

    @Inject
    public AService() {
    }

    public void processMessage(AccSqsMessage accSqsMessage) {
         ..
         internalSet = internalService.selectMappedInternal(accSqsMessage.getCode());
         ..
    }
}



public class InternalServiceImpl implements InternalService {

    @Inject
    PanelDao panelDao;

    @Inject
    public InternalServiceImpl() {
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Internal> selectMappedInternal(String code) {
       ..
       Optional<Panel> p = panelDao.findPanelByCode(code);
       ..
    }
}
```

Comment: without the code for class B, we can never help you other than to say "you are doing something wrong"

Comment: added a simplified version of the code

Comment: Getting the same problem with any class and in any test. Doesn't matter. Even simple `ObjectMapper` spy was not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally able to solve it as below.
My guess about cause of the problem is implementation class "InternalServiceImpl" for interface "InternalService" could not be injected properly to unit test class (despite it is working fine when injected to a business class), so during debugging, I was not able to see execution of methods in spy object.

After spying (without annonation) an explicitly provided implementation class, everything seems solved.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class Test {

  @InjectMocks
  AService  aService ;

  @InjectMocks
  InternalService  internalService = Mockito.spy(InternalServiceImpl.class);

  @Mock
  PanelDao panelDao;

  @Test
  public void test() { 
    ..
  }
}
```

Comment: Didn't work with `@InjectMocks`

Answer (score 0):

Adding `mockito-inline` dependency solved the problem for -

`mockito` version `4.11` on `Java 17`

Although [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65997640/7857701) answer gives the idea on why to use the module; to enable advance features. But not sure on whats the issue here.