# Unit test query dsl bindings

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, querydsl, powermockito

I have the following repostitory that uses query dsl bindings

```
    public interface StatusRepository extends
                PagingAndSortingRepository<Status, Long>,
                QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Status>,
                QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QStatus> {
        
            @Override
            default void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, @NotNull QStatus root) {
                bindings.bind(String.class).first((StringPath path, String value) -> 
 path.likeIgnoreCase(value.replace("_", "[_]")));
            }
```

I am writing unit test for `customize` method and having difficulties

```
@Test
    public void customize() {
        QuerydslBindings bindings = mock(QuerydslBindings.class);
        QStatus qstatus = mock(QStatus.class);
        QuerydslBindings.TypeBinder mock = 
        PowerMockito.mock(QuerydslBindings.TypeBinder.class);
        when(bindings.bind(String.class)).thenReturn(mock);
    
        statusRepository.customize(bindings, qstatusGroup);
    } 

Cannot mock/spy class org.springframework.data.querydsl.binding.QuerydslBindings$TypeBinder
Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
 - final class
```

I am using powermockito to mock QuerydslBindings.TypeBinder but it still says it cant be mocked

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53274463/what-is-mockito-inline-and-how-does-it-work-to-mock-final-methods ?

Answer (score 0):

Check QuerydslPredicateArgumentResolver how Spring works with binder.

The idea is to use the binder directly and check generated predicate

```
    @Test
void binding() {
    var predicateBuilder = new QuerydslPredicateBuilder(new DefaultConversionService(), SimpleEntityPathResolver.INSTANCE);
    var type = ClassTypeInformation.from(Status.class);
    var binder = new QuerydslBindingsFactory(SimpleEntityPathResolver.INSTANCE)
            .createBindingsFor(type, StatusCustomizer.class);
    var query = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    query.add("param", "value");
    
    Predicate predicate = predicateBuilder.getPredicate(type, query, binder);

    System.out.println(predicate.toString());
}
```