# Cannot mock method response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, junit5

I want to mockup the result from this SQL query:

```
   public List<RiskFilters> findRiskFiltersByTerminalIdAndType(int terminal_id, String filter_class) {
        String hql = "....";  
        TypedQuery<RiskFilters> query = entityManager.createQuery(hql, RiskFilters.class)....;
        List<RiskFilters> riskFilters = query.getResultList();
        return riskFilters;
    }
```

I tried this mockup configuration:

```
List<RiskFilters> riskFiltersList = new ArrayList<RiskFilters>();
        riskFiltersList.add(new RiskFilters()); 

        when(riskFilterService.findRiskFiltersByTerminalIdAndType(anyInt(), anyString())).thenReturn(riskFiltersList);
```

But I get NPE here:

```
List<RiskFilters> filter_list = riskFilterService.findRiskFiltersByTerminalIdAndType(11, "BinCountryCheckFilter");
```

Looks like the params of the mock are not correct. Do you know how to properly implement this?

Comment: could you show us the complete test method? Thanks

Comment: And the NPE‘s stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

I think need to `given(...).willReturn(...)`.

refer to https://www.baeldung.com/bdd-mockito

Answer (score 0):

It seems like riskFilterService is not mocked, in the test class you have to annotate RiskFilterService with @Mock, the class being tested with @InjectMocks and make sure you init all mocks, somthing like https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-junit-5-extension and [How to use Mockito with JUnit5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40961057/how-to-use-mockito-with-junit5)