# NullPointerException when mocking repository JUnit

Tags: java, testing, junit, rest

I have created a basic Rest API with a Controller, Service and Repository layer. I am now trying to write a unit test for the Service layer method that finds product by the product id. However, when I run the test it throws a NullPointerException in the line where I am trying to mock the repository findById() method.

The getProductById() method in the service layer is as follows:

`public Product getProductById(String id){ return productRepository.findById(id).orElse(null); }`

My test class for the service layer:

```
package com.product.Services;

import com.product.Entities.Product;
import com.product.Repositories.ProductRepository;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)

class ProductServiceTest {

   @InjectMocks
   ProductService productService;

   @Mock
   ProductRepository productRepository;

   @Test
   void getProductById() throws Exception {

      Product product = new Product();
      product.setId("001");
      product.setName("TV");
      product.setPrice(999.99);

      when(productRepository.findById("001").orElse(null)).thenReturn(product);
      assertEquals(product,productService.getProductById("001"));
   }
}
```

Attaching a picture of what the debugger shows:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried making the class / test function public? what mockito version are you using?

Comment: changing to public did not seem to solve it. The mockito version is org.mockito:mockito-core:3.3.3

Comment: Hi, Kris.
Have you tried declaring the `@Mock` annotations before the `@InjectMocks`?

Comment: @CarlosMancilla the order doesn't matter. But what Benoit suggests in his answer makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that 2 different versions of JUnit are used here:
`org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` is from JUnit5, while
`org.junit.runner.RunWith` is from JUnit4.

`RunWith` does not exist anymore in JUnit5.

In this specific case, I would use JUnit4 - i.e. use the annotation `org.junit.Test` (instead of `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`) to annotate your test.

[How to use Mockito with JUnit5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40961057/how-to-use-mockito-with-junit5) provides other valid solutions.

Comment: Fiddled around with the dependencies and imports and once I managed to get everything to match Junit5 it started working. Not really sure which change made it happen, but cheers mate!

Answer (score 1):

JUnit 5 uses *@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)* annotation, can you change *@RunWith* annotation and try again?

Comment: Yeah that was part of the change I needed to do to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You should mock the `findById` call, not the expression chained with `orElse`:

```
when(productRepository.findById("001")).thenReturn(product);
```

Comment: Correct, but that won't magically make `productRepository` not null.

Comment: Tried it and changing it did not make a difference. Think the issue is with repository being null rather than the statement itself.