# How to send @Autowired field in @InjectMocks

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, junit5

I am unit testing a class AuthController, which has this constructor

```
@Autowired
public AuthController(DynamicBeanFactory beanService) {
   Sysout(beanService); //here null is coming - Point-1
}
```

In Test Class, I have done:

```
@Mock
DynamicBeanFactory beanService;

@InjectMocks
AuthController authController(beanService);

- Below @Test are there -
```

Now when I am running this :

the value of beanService inside constructor above at `point-1` is coming **null**.

---

Also, when I am doing @Autowired at place of @InjectMocks it works.

> Below I have shared some questions people asked.

**Q) What is AuthController?**

A) It's just a class having that constructor I have shared above.

**Q) What is Dynamic Bean Factory ?**

A) It's a Service class something like this below :

```
@Service
public class DynamicBeanFactory

   @Autowired
   public DynamicBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory)
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to use `@Mock` instead of `@Autowired`, also don't confuse spring with mocking. You shouldn't really use spring in your unit tests

Comment: @Lino still null is coming inside contructor.

Comment: Please provide a complete [mre], currently your code doesn't compile. What is `AuthController authController(beanService)`?

Comment: I have updated the question, please check.

Comment: It still isn't a [mre]. How are you running your tests? How are you initializing your mocks (are you using `MockitoAnnotations.init(this)` in a `@BeforeEach`, or are you using `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`)? There's still a lot of open questions

Comment: I don't have @BeforeEach, MockitoAnnotations.init(this. What I am using is this -->@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to use Mockito with JUnit5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40961057/how-to-use-mockito-with-junit5)

Comment: nope it doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `@Mock` remember to add `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` to your test class otherwise it won't initialize the mocks.

Comment: I have put just @SpringBootTest, should I include @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) with that ?

Comment: As mentioned in the comments you shouldn't be using Spring for unit test, you can replace it with `@RunWith`

Comment: I did it, it is still giving null

Comment: Remove the parameter of authController `@InjectMocks AuthController authController;`

Comment: now AuthController itself is coming null inside @Test method

Comment: Tavo, the reason it is coming null is because @InjectMocks AuthController authC; is passing the params as null and due to which it is giving NPE.

Answer (score -1):

You can use @MockBean for @Autowired dependencies.
Like this:

```html
@MockBean
DynamicBeanFactory beanService;
```

Try this, it's working for me. I assumed that `AuthController` has a constructor which takes `DynamicBeanFactory` as a parameter and there is no other dependency.

```html
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class TestApplicationTests {
            
    @InjectMocks
    DynamicBeanFactory d;
    
    @MockBean 
    AuthController a;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Assert.notNull(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Still "null" is coming in the constructor.

Comment: Can you share the code snippet of init() and setUp().

Comment: I have updated the question. I don;t have init() and setup() in my code. Please mention if I need to put them.

Comment: @AshutoshTiwari, Try the code I have provided above.

Comment: Ok trying this, Manjeet while I am trying testing, the application.properties are not picked by the class I am doing testing for. Do I need to use some annotation or something so that @ Value starts working back. FYI: It works if I do @ Autowired  in place of @ InjectMocks

Comment: Not sure about the first part of your question. Yes, it will work if you use @Autowired because it will create an object which is equivalent to running your actual code. Ideally testing should be done in the following way:
controller -> service -> dao
While testing controller layer, you should mock service layer to mimick it's behaviour and to avoid actual service call. Same for service and Dao.

Comment: Manjeet, the reason your code is not working because I have paramterized constructor whereas by writing @Autowired AuthController, it is giving the params as null that's wht NPE is coming.