# Instead of Stubing, Mockito is calling the action method

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

Below is my test code.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

public class classA {

    @Mock
    EncSercice encService;

    @InjectMocks
    ServiceClass service;
    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
      MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }


    @Test
    public void testEncryptRegisterTransactionPayload() {
        
        ValidRequest request = new ValidRequest();

        try {
            
            Mockito.when(encService.callFn(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(String[].class)))
                    .thenReturn("Stubbed encrypted message");

            service.sendPayload(request);
            Mockito.verify(encService).callFn(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(String[].class));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here I'm trying to mock/stub the `encService.callFn` method. But when i run it, It's actually calling method. I can see the logs which I have mentioned in `callFn` method. Even i have tried using `doReturn().when()`, Still it's calling the actual method. How can I solve this?

EncService class:

```
class EncSercice implements EncSerciceImp {
    public String callFn(final String req, final String[] keys) throws Exception {
    byte[] output = // calling a private method and passing req and keys as args....
    return new String(output);
}
}

// ServiceClass  code 
public void sendPayload(final ValidRequest  req) {

    // some code imp..
    EncSercice encService = new EncSercice();
    String str = encService.callFn(req, keys);
}
```

note: `callFn` will return a dynamic string.

Comment: Don’t forget to annotate your test class, depending On whether you are using Junit4 or 5 - see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49655834/681444

Comment: @racraman I have added `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` and also `@BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }` still the actual function is getting called.

Comment: Are you using JUnit 4 or JUnit 5?  You shouldn't need to do both of those things, since the MockitoExtension actually calls initMocks.

Comment: And can you show us the `EncSercice` class?  There might be something about it that stops it from being stubbed, for example, if it's final.

Comment: I have updated the question and provided `EncService`.  I use `spring-boot-starter-test`. I think it has `junit 5x`. Spring verion 2.7.8.

Comment: How does this even work? you provide 2 parameters for the method callFn() in test, but this method needs only one

Comment: In addition to the above question about parameters, must also ask how `ServiceClass` is calling `EncSercice` - is it calling `callFn` directly, or only via `execute` ?  If the latter, then even if Mockito was set up correctly, then your `when` would never have any effect (since the mock object does not have the actual `execute` code), so you would need to add a`when` for the `execute` call.

Comment: You still haven't shown the annotation you are using. Please edit your question with your actual code. Also, please add the code for ServiceClass. And answer the question @Feelfree asked.

Comment: Feelfree, I have edited the question. I had to mask some code. 
For service code, I'm just using @Service annotation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are my mocked methods not called when executing a unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74027324/why-are-my-mocked-methods-not-called-when-executing-a-unit-test) You create a `new` instance in your method → the Mockito mock is never used (definitely a dupe)

Comment: yes, I was creating `new` instance of EncService. I have used `@Autowired` for `EncService`  on service class, then the test case passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my service class I have created object instance with `new` keyword.
Instead of that, When I have used

```
@Autowired
private EncService encService;
```

Then the test case passed.

Answer (score 1):

The class being tested, ServiceClass, should have EncsService as a field, so that mockito could inject it as a dependency.

```
public class ServiceClass {
   private EncSercice encService;
   public SeviceClass(EncSercice enc) 
   {
      this.encService = enc;
   }

   public void sendPayload(final ValidRequest  req) {

    // some code imp...
    String str = encService.call(req, keys);
```

Comment: With your code test case is passed but the actual code was failing b'coz i wasn't using constructor.