# Mockito InjectMocks not working but constructor call does

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, mockito

I'm using Kotlin with Mockito. Given these dependencies:

```kotlin
    @Mock
    private lateinit var tokenService: TokenService

    @Mock
    private lateinit var jwtDecoder: JwtDecoder

    @Mock
    private lateinit var passwordEncoder: PasswordEncoder

    @Mock
    private lateinit var authManager: AuthenticationManager

    @Mock
    private lateinit var mailLoginUserService: MailLoginUserService

    @Mock
    private lateinit var simpleMailService: SimpleMailService
```

I though the following codes should be equivalent.

First Variant:

```kotlin
@InjectMocks
private lateinit var underTest: MailLoginService
```

Second Variant:

```kotlin
private lateinit var underTest: MailLoginService

    @BeforeEach
    fun setup() {
    underTest = MailLoginService(
            tokenService,
            jwtDecoder,
            passwordEncoder,
            authManager,
            mailLoginUserService,
            simpleMailService
        )
    }
```

I know that BeforeEach is called before every test giving a knew instance of the MailLoginService but I'm only running one test.

In the test I specified

```kotlin
given(passwordEncoder.encode(anyString()))
            .willReturn("EncodedPassword")
```

Inside the tested method of MailLoginService the method passwordEncoder.encode is called. With the second variant (the manual constructor call) everything works fine. But with the first variant (InjectMocks) I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: encode(...) must not be null
```

I'd like to use InjectMocks as it reduces Code. Does anybody know why this problem occurs and how to fix it?

Comment: This may help you: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40961057/how-to-use-mockito-with-junit5) - not sure about Kotlin, but you need to tell Mockito to run somehow (annotation or static method call).